# Having trouble adding images to an annotation in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have queried an array of NSData objects (which when converted will become images) from Parses backend like so:

```
 var query = PFUser.query()
            query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:geopoint)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

for object in objects {

   var user:PFUser = object as PFUser

     var otherUserImages = [NSData]()

     otherUserImages.append(user["image"] as NSData)

     }
})
```

I now have an array of NSData objects which I want to use as images as an annotation on a map.

So I have created a function:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        var view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

                for userImage in self.otherUserImages {

                view.canShowCallout = true

                var dataImage = UIImage(data: userImage)

                var userMapImage = UIImageView(image: dataImage)

                view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = userMapImage

                }
            }
```

Now this places a image as a annotation but only at `array[0]` I can't seem to get all the images in as annotations?

Can someone please tell me what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me whether you want to handle each one of your images as an annotation, or you prefer handling all of them as a single annotation.

In the first case, it seems that you are using the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method incorrectly.

I assume that you have created your `MKAnnotation` objects and added them to your `MKMapView`, since `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` is correctly called.

Now, what you should consider is that `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` is called for each annotation. Then, for each call you should return a `MKPinAnnotationView`, and you should associate a single image (view) to each of them. So, you need define a mechanism so that you can associate `MKAnnotation` objects to your images, then just use that image in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`. If you provide more details about `MKAnnotation`, I could be able to help further.

On the other hand, you could think of "joining" all of your images into a single `UIView` to be associated to a single annotation. In this case you would do something like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    var view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    var imageView = UIView(frame:...)
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = userMapImage

    for userImage in self.otherUserImages {

            view.canShowCallout = true
            var dataImage = UIImage(data: userImage)
            var userMapImage = UIImageView(image: dataImage)
            imageView.addSubview(userMapImage)
    }
}
```

To be honest, I am not sure it makes really sense to "join" all images into one, but you will know better...

On another coin, you should also think about [Reusing Annotation Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:)

EDIT:

What you need to establish is a relationship between your `annotationCustom` objects and the objects in `self.otherUserImages`. I have no idea how you do that. Maybe you need to add a new property to your `annotationCustom` class to hold the `NSData` that represents the image... or you might prefer converting your `self.otherUserImages` into an `NSDictionary` and associate to each annotation `name` the corresponding image data.

Once you have done that, then you could use

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    var view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

    if let myAnnotation = annotation as? annotationCustom {

            view.canShowCallout = true
            var dataImage = myAnnotation.dataForImage
            var userMapImage = UIImageView(image: dataImage)
            view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = userMapImage
    }
    return view;
}
```

Once you get the above working, you could think of using `dequeue` to improve performance and memory usage:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

static NSString *viewIdentifier = @"annotationView";
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewIdentifier];
if (annotationView == nil) {

    if let myAnnotation = annotation as? annotationCustom {

            view.canShowCallout = true
            var dataImage = myAnnotation.dataForImage
            var userMapImage = UIImageView(image: dataImage)
            view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = userMapImage
    }
    return view;
}
```

I hope the `myAnnotation.dataForImage` bit is sufficiently clear...

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I am trying to do your first option, handle all my images as single annotations. I have created a annotation class with initialisers -  Coordinate, title, subtitle. and then created the annotation with the code :  `var otherAnnotation = annotationCustom(coordinate: newFinalLocation, title: name, subtitle: gender)
                            self.myMap.addAnnotation(otherAnnotation)` sorry this is so messy if you can help anymore?

Comment: Yes this has helped alot, I feel I am almost there. I have created s NSData object in my `annotationCustom` class to hold the data like so: `var dataImage = [NSData]()` I am then trying to append it from my MapViewController like so: `var annotationData = annotationCustom().dataImage      annotationData.append(user["image"] as NSData)` although I am getting the error: "missing argument for parameter 'coordinate' in call" how do I get around this as I just want to add my data to the `annotationCustom` data object not initialise the actual class? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I've managed to sort this now, I was doing something really simple wrong. Thanks for all your help!